# Assign array values to top level object javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, dictionary, key-value

At the bottom is a slimmed down version of a JSON file that I am trying to parse.  I would like to create individual objects that have a key for the team name and the player name.

How would I go about using the team name and mapping to each individual player and receive something like this (using javascript):

```
[
{ name: 'Dallas Stars', playerName: 'Alexander Radulov'},
{ name: 'Dallas Stars', playerName: 'Ben Bishop'},
{ name: 'Dallas Stars', playerName: 'Jamie Benn'}
...
{ name: 'Columbus Blue Jackets', playerName: 'Pierre-Luc Dubois'}
]
```

From this JSON:

```
[ { name: 'Dallas Stars',
        roster:
         [ 'Alexander Radulov',
           'Ben Bishop',
           'Jamie Benn',
           'Tyler Pitlick',
           'Miro Heiskanen' ] },
      { name: 'Los Angeles Kings',
        roster:
         [ 'Jonathan Quick',
           'Jonny Brodzinski',
           'Oscar Fantenberg' ] },
      { name: 'San Jose Sharks',
        roster:
         [ 'Joe Thornton',
           'Brent Burns',
           'Joe Pavelski',
           'Antti Suomela' ] },
      { name: 'Columbus Blue Jackets',
        roster:
         [ 'Sonny Milano',
           'Brandon Dubinsky',
           'Nick Foligno',
           'Pierre-Luc Dubois' ] } ]
```

Essentially I am trying to map a top level key pair to individual players.  I have tried searching through all lodash functions as well and haven't stumbled upon the correct way to do this.

Is there a way to use a flat map and have the team name used multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Map over the original array, then for each item being "mapped" map over its roster and create your desired object. Finally, since the resulting array will be 2d, flatten it:

```js
var data = [{ name: 'Dallas Stars', roster: ['Alexander Radulov', 'Ben Bishop', 'Jamie Benn', 'Tyler Pitlick', 'Miro Heiskanen' ] }, { name: 'Los Angeles Kings', roster: ['Jonathan Quick', 'Jonny Brodzinski', 'Oscar Fantenberg' ] }, { name: 'San Jose Sharks', roster: ['Joe Thornton', 'Brent Burns', 'Joe Pavelski', 'Antti Suomela' ] }, { name: 'Columbus Blue Jackets', roster: ['Sonny Milano', 'Brandon Dubinsky', 'Nick Foligno', 'Pierre-Luc Dubois' ] } ];

var res = data
  .map(({name, roster}) =>
    roster.map(playerName => ({name, playerName})))
  .flat();

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Wow this helped a lot.  Didn't realize I could pass name into the second map again.  How do I get around this "TypeError: data.map(...).flat is not a function".  I read online some browsers don't support map, but for just running node app,js do I need to install a specific package?

Comment: Yes, it could be that `flat` isn't supported on the NodeJS version you're running. You can try using something like Babel (https://babeljs.io/) to get around it.

Comment: I was running version 9.5.  Switched to 11.1 and now it's working.  Simple fix, great thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the outer array items, and then inside of each of those, iterate over the `roster` too. `reduce` is usually the most appropriate method for transforming an array into another array on a non-one-to-one basis:

```js
const input=[{name:'Dallas Stars',roster:['Alexander Radulov','Ben Bishop','Jamie Benn','Tyler Pitlick','Miro Heiskanen']},{name:'Los Angeles Kings',roster:['Jonathan Quick','Jonny Brodzinski','Oscar Fantenberg']},{name:'San Jose Sharks',roster:['Joe Thornton','Brent Burns','Joe Pavelski','Antti Suomela']},{name:'Columbus Blue Jackets',roster:['Sonny Milano','Brandon Dubinsky','Nick Foligno','Pierre-Luc Dubois']}];

const output = input.reduce((a, { name, roster }) => {
  roster.forEach((playerName) => {
    a.push({ name, playerName });
  });
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```